# How to see all navigation emenets in S1 running on my desktop browser?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I have a couple of custom object in tabs an want to see them in S1. On my Android and iOS-Devices everything works fine. I see an element **...more** in the navigation and clicking on it brings me to the custom objects. So far so good.

BUT: for strong reasons I need to use S1 in my desktop-browser. And as an unfortunate there is no **...more** visible to click. And as a consequence possibly no way to see my custom objects.

I got one tip, to pin the object in the global search. But that too did not bring it up in S1 running on desktop browser. Also ohter elements of the navigations seem to be messed up, disaranged and missing.

**iOS (with ...more and everything as expected)**

[image]

**Chrome (Windows 7 and missing elements)**

[image]

**Device Mode doesn't help either:**

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running chrome in developer mode (F12) and click on the device icon (right before Elements tab) to pass the user agent string to the app?

Comment: did not help either. Same missing navigation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're logging in as two different users; simply navigating to items you expect to use in your browser should be enough to trigger a more link. Here's what I see in my browser:

[image: Salesforce1 Mobile in Mozilla Firefox Browser]

As you can see, the More link appears, although it's missing the ellipsis. Simply navigate to the objects you want to use in mobile, and they should appear in the recent items list.

Comment: 100% sure it's the same user. Unfortunately, there are no more links and missing navigation + disarranged elements. For me it's also reproducible in Safari-Mobil. Navigation is very incomplete. ONLY the mobile app shows everything. I'm simultaneously logged in with the same user. Different navigation.

Comment: This happens **only at this single Org**. Tested on a different Org, all runs fine and looks like your screenshot (only ellipsis missing). Will be hard to nail down the reason why this specific org fails....